# Starting another script using a button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to run another script within a script using a button in tkinter

I have tried two methods one being

```
import os

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    #initilization
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):      
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Battery Life Calculator")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)


#raise each page to the front
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def helloCallBack():
        os.system('python test2.py')

#the start page        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page         1",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))                  
        button.pack()
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo))                 
        button1.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Graph page",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageThree))              
        button2.pack()
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="execute test",command=lambda:controller.helloCallBack)               
        button3.pack()
```

No errors are given but when I hit execute nothing happens

The other method i tried was to

```
import test2
```

but it runs the script automatically and it prints "i am a test"

I should note the script i am trying to call is simply a test and just prints "i am a test"

any help is appreciated!

thanks

****edit****

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import test2







LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):


#initilization
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):      



        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Battery Life Calculator")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)



#raise each page to the front
    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()







#the start page        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))

        button.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo))

        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Graph page",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageThree))

        button2.pack()

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="execute test",command=test2.main)

        button3.pack()











class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to start page",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo))

        button1.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button1.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Page One",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))

        button1.pack()

class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Graph Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button1.pack()




app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

test2.p is as follows

```
def main():

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print("Executing as main program")
        print("Value of __name__ is: ", __name__)
        main()
```

Comment: This isn't a whole program - just two class declarations. If this is what you have then it isn't surprising it doesn't do anything.

Comment: i'm fully aware its not a whole program the program works fine apart from calling my function. I simply added the instances in which i have been trying to use this script.

Comment: It would be good to have a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) so that others can try running the program to help them solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is not recommended for that. If you have another python script you should definitely import it.

About the second method:
My guess is that the script `test2.py` is written without

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And that's why it shoot you message when you import it.

Comment: Thank you i hadn't done that! What will my button code be to run the scrip? I currently have 

 button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Graph page",command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageThree))

 to change between pages. Thanks

Comment: i now have my test as 

def main():

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print("Executing as main program")
        print("Value of __name__ is: ", __name__)
        main()

and my import as 

import test2

and my button as 

button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="execute test",command=lambda:test2.main)

when i hit the button i've no error but nothing happens?


apologise for how hard that is to read not sure how to embed code in comments

Comment: you don't need lambda if you run function without arguments (and without `()`). Put your code in question. In comment it is unreadable. I thing you use `if __name__` in wrong way - in wrong place - you have to use it outside of `main()`. If you import test2.py but you don't run `test2.py` directly then you don't need `if __name__` but you still have to keep code inside function.

Comment: Just pasted code into the question, worked when i tried your code! Thanks For your help!